# Javascript: How to get element by variable name within the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
function(){
var btn=document.createElement("BUTTON");
var t=document.createTextNode("yes");
btn.appendChild(t);
document.body.appendChild(btn);

document.getElementById(btn).onclick = function() {next()};
}
```

I know this is wrong because btn is a variable name, not an Id. Could someone help me change my 6th line of code so that I can run the function next() after onclick of btn?

**I need to have my commands inside this function, and cannot make an id outside this function.

Answer (score 1):

You already have a reference to the element, so use that

```
function functionName() {

    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    var t   = document.createTextNode("yes");

    btn.appendChild(t);

    document.body.appendChild(btn);

    btn.addEventListener('click', next, false);

}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gsmV5/)

Answer (score 0):

You have already button reference in `btn` variable so attach event with `btn` variable see blow

```
function(){
var btn=document.createElement("BUTTON");
var t=document.createTextNode("yes");
btn.appendChild(t);
document.body.appendChild(btn);

btn.onclick = function() {next()};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**btn** is not an id, it is a variable which has the reference of the button object.

You can add onclick event directly to **btn** variable:

```
btn.onclick = next;
```